# Puppeteer: different results each run, iterating over various elementHandle.hover()

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am scraping images from a site. I am using .hover() on a list of elements to change a main image viewer element. It appears to work, but inconsistent results. The main image change will only occur sometimes. for example:

6 image tiles, should have 6 unique src urls [A, B, C, D, E, F]
What actually happens is: [A, B, C, C, C, C] or [A, B, C, D, D, D] or some combination like that.

I imagine that I should wait somehow for the page to load after each hover? I've tried page.waitFor(500), which breaks the result entirely and produces [A, A, A, A, A, A]

Reduced code example:

```
    const browser = await pptr.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`https://www.somesite.com`);
    let images = [];
    const imageItems = await page.$$('ul[class="images-view-list"] > li > div'); //Image selector tabs
    for (let image of imageItems) {
        await image.hover();
        const imageContainer = await page.$('img[class="magnifier-image"]'); //main image element
        images.push({'Image Src': await (await imageContainer.getProperty('src')).jsonValue()});
    }
```

SOLVED: it was a popup frame blocking the hovered element from viewport... silly mistake... When in doubt, pptr.launch({headless: false})